# JavaFx MediaPlayer can't play my mp3 and m4a files converted by ffmpeg

Tags: javafx, ffmpeg, mp3, media-player, m4a

I record some .wav files from microphone, and convert it to mp3 and m4a files. These files can be played with my desktop player correctly.

Then in my JavaFX program, I play them as:

```
String fileUri = file.toURI().toString();
Media media = new Media(fileUri);
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

But there is no sound, and no errors.

I use `ffmpeg` to view them:

#### ffmpeg -i demo.m4a

```
Input #0, aac, from 'demo.m4a':
  Duration: 00:00:54.00, bitrate: 132 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 132 kb/s
```

#### ffmpeg -i hello.mp3

```
Input #0, mp3, from 'hello.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:01.12, start: 0.069063, bitrate: 49 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 16000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 48 kb/s
```

And use this command to convert by ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i hello.wav hello.mp3
```

Not sure where is wrong.

---

Update: finally I use this command to generate mp3 which can be played by JavaFx

```
 ffmpeg -i hello.wav -f mp2 hello.mp3
```

(also can add `-c:a libmp3lame` to generate smaller size mp3)

Seems like JavaFx only supports `mp2` format of mp3 files.

Comment: You can read which media types are supported in the package Javaodc of [`javafx.scene.media`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) (link is for Java 10).

Comment: This is a great question, JavaFX needs improvements for sure on the Media supporting part.

Comment: @Slaw Thanks for the link. Actually I've read it but that doesn't fully resolve my problem. E.g. It says it support `m4a` and `aac`, but you can see my `demo.m4a` fits the requirement, but it still can't be played